# Can't access EC2 WebApp from the web

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, web-applications, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows WebApp hosted on IIS on an EC2.

I can access it using the public IP but this IP change when the instance restart, so I associated an Elastic IP but the issue is I can't access the app using this Elastic IP : 404 - File or directory not found.

I checked the Inbound rules on the related security group to authorize 0.0.0.0/0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the Bindings in IIS : IIS -> Sites -> Your Site -> Right click -> Edit Bindings and add your IP